# Rails middleware to access API without Access Control Allow Origin header

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, same-origin-policy

Our goal is to create a rails app that will periodically get data from an online cloud POS service through its API. The data to be gathered is inventory information for certain accounts, if the quantity of a certain item goes to a certain level the app will send an email to a user. Also, this app will be used in the future to send push notification to android devices. My question is, will my rails app be affected by the same origin policy?If so, is there a workaround for this. I've tried using curl before and it works, but when I use javascript the server responds with an error.

Comment: Do i need to allow those headers on my app?I don't think I need my app to allow those headers since its only middleware for android app, and android apps aren't constrained by the same origin policy.The problem lies within the service I'm connecting to.Their server doesn't allow Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing.

Comment: oh, its from browser to their server? in this case, you can only use jsonp

Comment: nope, its server to server.xD.

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/a39X3.jpg here's the link for the image of a diagram  of how the software works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no workaround for [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) - it's a standard way of protecting your server from random access. As `@apnediving` mentioned, you can use the [rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to manage the CORS policy on YOUR SERVER

If you're relying on other servers for data, you'll have to update their CORS policies to allow you to connect to them. The CORS policy is just a gatekeeper for the "host" server

Essentially, all you need to do is permit a series of [endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) (urls) to allow access from third parties (typically through `xhr` -- which is why you're receiving an error). From what I can see, you'll need to sort out accessing the third party API from your app - that's under the remit of the POS service provider

Comment: If you give us some more context, we'll be in a better position to help

Comment: give me 5 minutes I'll be posting a diagram on what the app will do.

Comment: Looking at it, why don't you just use Curl to retrieve data from the API? Javascript is only for asynchronous requests anyway

Comment: Thank you guys!I can now connect to the API, I used OPEN-URI instead of cURL. I didn't know that javascript is only for asynchronous request, I thought that server to server request won't work. The problem that I know have is this during every set interval my server must get data from the API. My app must mimic the contents of the data from the API call (my app has its own database). I need to know an efficient way of doing this, since there maybe thousands of records and I need to update it depending on the changes in data(e.g. updating a row, or adding a new row if it doesn't exist yet)